# How does Parquet handles SparseVector Columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I'm very new to PySpark. I was building a tfidf and want to store it in disk as an intermediate result. Now the IDF scoring gives me a SparseVector representation.

However when trying to save it as Parquet, I'm getting OOM. I'm not sure if it internally converts the SparseVector to Dense as in that case it will lead to some 25k columns and according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/PARQUET-222) thread, saving such big data in columnar format can lead to OOM.

So, any idea on what can be the case? I'm having executor memory as 8g and operating on a 2g CSV file.

Should I try increasing the memory or save it in CSV instead of Parquet? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

As pointed out, that Spark performs lazy evaluation, the error can be because of an upstream stage, I tried a show and a collect before the write. They seemed to run fine without throwing errors. So, is it still some issue related to Parquet or I need some other debugging?

Answer (score 6):

Parquet doesn't provide native support for Spark ML / MLlib Vectors and neither are these first class citizens in Spark SQL.

Instead, Spark represents `Vectors` using `struct` fields with three fields:

- `type` - `ByteType`
- `size` - `IntegerType` (optional, only for `SparseVectors`)
- `indices` - `ArrayType(IntegerType)`  (optional, only for `SparseVectors`)
- `values` - `ArrayType(DoubleType)`

and uses metadata  to distinguish these from plain `structs` and UDT wrappers to map back to external types. No conversion between sparse and dense representation is needed. Nonetheless, depending on the data, such representation might require comparable memory, to the full dense array.

Please note that that OOM on write are not necessarily related to the writing process itself. Since Spark is in general lazy, the exception can be caused by any of the upstream stages.

Comment: Wow! That was really a very informative answer. Learnt many new things from it. However I have done a show and collect just before the write to verify if it is caused by any upstream code. But both went well without throwing error. Only the write back is giving it